# Notification settings aren't being retained

Tags: notifications, macos

After upgrading an iMac and MacBook Air from Mavericks to Yosemite, changes to Notifications aren't being retained:

- Looking at the Notifications Preference Pane - there are a set of apps with Notification settings.
- Changing Notification settings for any of these apps works - ie I can change the alert style, whether notifications appear in Notification Center, etc.

  - These settings are respected until I reboot / logout, at which point they revert back the original settings.
  - New apps will appear in the preference pane when they are run. Notification settings can be changed. After rebooting, the app disappears from the notification preference pane until I run it again, at which point it appears with default settings.

So what seems to be happening is that these settings aren't being saved to disk. I have:

- repaired permissions
- deleted the `~/Library/Application Support/NotificationCenter` folder

None of this had made any difference. Does anyone know where these settings are stored?

Comment: I am having the same issues. Unfortunately, my developer account has expired and I'm not re-upping for probably another month (we are switching over to a business account). This was something I was going to send in on the dev bug reporter. I've also tried everything including an SMC reset. Still no luck. I noticed it because I disable notifications for gfxCardStatus. Now every time my MBPr 15" switches between the integrated and discrete graphics, the banner pops up every time. I went from Mavericks to Yosemite, so it wasn't something to do with going from Mtn Lion to Yosemite. Like you, I can

Comment: Same here. As a temporary measure I've disconnected a lot of accounts that generate messages. Too distracting. Will try http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-completely-disable-notification-center-in-mac-os-x/ if i get desperate.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem with the notification center not retaining my settings. Like anu, I've tried repairing permissions and removing `~/Library/Application Support/NotificationCenter` and `~/Preferences/com.apple.notificationcenter.plist`, but nothing has worked. I need to get rid of those %&*! Facebook notifications!!!

Comment: I'm having this same issue and submitted an Apple Bug report (18762327) for it.

Comment: Thanks for including the radar. It sure looks like a bug to me as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fixed:

[This thread on the Apple forums](https://discussions.apple.com/message/26894468#26894468) is the key:

- Open the Library folder in your Home folder.
- In the Library folder, open the Application Support folder.
- Locate the folder named NotificationCenter. Drag this folder to the desktop.
- Next, open the Terminal application and enter the following

.

```
cd `getconf DARWIN_USER_DIR`
rm -rf com.apple.notificationcenter 
killall usernoted; killall NotificationCenter
```

- Restart your computer.

The issue is clearly to do with the NotificationCenter database. There are 3 files:

- db
- db-shm
- db.wal

In my case `db.wal` was a 0 byte file compared with 1.9MB on a correctly working Yosemite install. Permissions were correctly set, but looks as if Yosemite wasn't writing to it. Only deleting `db.wal` didn't fix the problem - another 0 byte file was created on restart. Deleting everything works though!

Comment: Note: In the forum it is pointed out, that you have to restart the computer 2 times to make the changes work.

Comment: You really only need to reboot once. The second reboot really just proves that the fix works.

Comment: This was super annoying. Your fix worked for me. Thanks anu!